# Subitems in main menu uncentered

Tags: menu, nav

for some reason the subitems are not in the middle, looks like they have a margin left for some reason. Can you tell me what is wrong and how to fix it?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Responsive Menu Tutorial</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS-1.css">
</head>

<body>
    <ul class="egmenu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li>
    <a href="#" class="has-sub">Products</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Computers</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Phones</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Tablets</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>



</body>
</html>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul.egmenu {  
    background: #333; 
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%; 
}

ul.egmenu > li { 
    float: left; 
    position: relative;  
}

ul.egmenu ul {
    background: #444; 
    display: none; 
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; top: 100%;
}

ul.egmenu ul li {
    text-align: center;
}

ul.egmenu a { 
    cursor: pointer; 
    display: block; 
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 30px; 
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul.egmenu li { list-style: none; }

ul.egmenu li:hover { background: #555;  }
ul.egmenu li:hover ul { display: block;  }
```

P.S. It would also be nice if you tell me where can i find some lessons or anything to fix my understanding of CSS, as it appears that codecademy is not enough.

Comment: There is no "ul.egmenu ul li"? I guess it should be "ul.egmenu li ul li".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed some of the important attributes, i recreated your navbar

Here's the JSFiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/y2641f0w/3/

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <ul class="egmenu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li>
    <a href="#" class="has-sub">Products</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Computers</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Phones</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Tablets</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
  body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

}

ul.egmenu{
  background: #333; 
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%; 

}

ul.egmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #444;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul.egmenu li {  
  font-size: 25px; 
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: left;
}

ul.egmenu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
  transition: .3s background-color;
}
ul.egmenu a:hover {
  background-color:  #555;
}

ul.egmenu a.active {
  background-color: #aaa;
  color: #444;
  cursor: default;
}

/* Sub Menus */
ul.egmenu li li {
  font-size: 15px;
}



@media screen and (min-width: 650px) {
  ul.egmenu li {
    width: 130px;
    border-bottom: none;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
  }

  ul.egmenu a {
    border-bottom: none;
  }

ul.egmenu > ul > li {
    text-align: center;
  }

  ul.egmenu > ul > li > a {
    padding-left: 0;
  }

  /* Sub Menus */
  ul.egmenu li ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: inherit;
  }

ul.egmenu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
  }

  ul.egmenu li ul li {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

You can refer to followings to get more knowledge about NavBars

- [w3Schools](http://cssmenumaker.com/blog/6-exceptional-menu-bar-navigation-designs)
- [CSS Menumaker](http://cssmenumaker.com/blog/6-exceptional-menu-bar-navigation-designs)